# Guarantee execution of Javascript AJAX before any document.location change

Tags: javascript

I want to track visitors on my website considering many factors. I do this tracking through continuous Javascript monitoring and sending collected data to a server in real-time through AJAX calls.

My problem is that after a user clicks a normal link or an a DOM element handled by JS which changes document.location, the last click is not recorded by my script and send to my server.

I thought I should change every DOM's element onClick event to first let my script do his things (preventingDefault) and then continue to execute the original onClick event but this solution seems inappropriate and a bit risky (what if any onClick event gets created after I first changed all events, I can't do that scan&modify continuously for obvious reasons).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Post code which you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.onbeforeunload`:

```
function getTrack(e){
    //do your stuff
}

window.onbeforeunload=getTrack;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think depending on the data you try to track, you should try and look into Google Analytics for this, it tracks it automatically.

Comment: C'mon man, I am designing a Google-Analytics-like-tool and you tell me to use that? I want myself to be able what they do, not to use their product. Also, Google-Analytics does not track the location of your user's mouse when he clicks on a link.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make sure the request from onbeforeunload or onunload will make it to the server. Modern day browsers cancel the requests.

If you want to make sure than any outgoing domain calls make it to your logs, you basically need to hijack all of the clicks and cancel the action. You would send the Ajax call and when it is done, you do the page navigation.

Answer (score 0):

May be an way using jquery.

```
<a class=' location'  href=' page.php'> click </a>
<script>
$(document).ready (function (e){
      $(".location").click (function(){
      e.preventDefaults();
     var link = $(this).attr("href");
      $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"update_visitoi_infoo.php",
            data:{v_info:"value"},
            success:function(resp) {
                   document.location.href=link;
            }
     });
   });
});
```